# why create-react-app create project and yarn start has error 'Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined'?

Tags: create-react-app

i'm use create-react-app create project, and after yarn eject, i change webpack.config.js 'entry' propetry, and paths 'module.exports={}', when i yarn start, i get the error 'Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined'. i don't know where is mistakes.

env: macos 14
node: v10.13.0
npm: v6.11.3
yarn: 1.15.2
react: v16.9.0

webpack.config.js:

```js
entry: {
      index: [
        paths.appIndexJs, 
        isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient')
      ].filter(Boolean),
      query: [
        paths.appQueryJs, 
        isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient')
      ].filter(Boolean),
      order: [
        paths.appOrderJs, 
        isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient')
      ].filter(Boolean),
      ticketPage: [
        paths.appTicketPageJs, 
        isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient')
      ].filter(Boolean)
    },
```

paths.js

```
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),

  // this is new
  appQueryHtml: resolveApp('public/query.html'),  
  appOrderHtml: resolveApp('public/order.html'),  
  appticketPageHtml: resolveApp('public/ticketPage.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index/index'),
  appQueryJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/query/index'),
  appTicketPageJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/ticketPage/index'),
  appOrderJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/order/index'),
  // new over

  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
  appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
  proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
};
```

i expect running 'yarn start', the react project is ok!

project folder:

[image: folder]
<sub>(source: [labike.xyz](http://img.labike.xyz/create-react-app-error.png))</sub>

error:

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [labike.xyz](http://img.labike.xyz/react-folder.png))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

i found the error in paths.js:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    appTicketPage: ...
}
```

i'm write error!